# strtok() ignoring 0 values if first part of string is 0

Tags: c, strtok

I have the following code that takes a string parameter from the command line and is supposed to, first, split it into two individual strings, and, second, convert each of them to integer values:

```
int numOne = 0, numTwo = 0;
char *tmp, *end;

tmp = strtok(argv[1], ":");
numOne = strtol(tmp, &end, 10);
if (errno == ERANGE) {
    printf("range error\n");
    break;
}
while (tmp != NULL) {
    numTwo = strtol(tmp, &end, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        printf("range error\n");
        break;
    }
    tmp = strtok(NULL, argv[1]);
}
```

The problem is: This code works fine if the CL parameter looks like "1:500". However, if it is "0:500", the values stored in numOne and numTwo are 0 and 5, respectively. If the first value is 0, strtok() seems to ignore any 0-values afterwards and I never get values like 50, 500, 5000, etc. in numTwo.

Please help me understand why that is, and how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: `errno = 0;` should be applied before a `strtol()` else `if (errno == ERANGE)` may be true due to prior history.

Comment: That is happening in my program before the code part shown here.

Comment: Another minor point: `int numOne` --> `long numOne` else code may miss out of range detection as `LONG_MAX` may be greater than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
tmp = strtok(NULL, argv[1]);
```

should probably be:

```
tmp = strtok(NULL, ":");
```

You're currently passing the <s>original string</s> shortened string created by the first call of `strtok` as the delimiter.

Comment: Not exactly the original string. It is the shortened string created by the first call of `strtok`.